# QGIS Network Analysis Control and Plugins

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, network-analyst, transportation, isochrone

I am trying to create Isocrones in QGIS for network analysis. I am able to accomplish this using the plugin ORS Tools from my transit stop using a drive time of 5-, 10-, and 15-minutes. However, the total control when using the ORS Tools compared to that of, say, ArcMap's Network Analysis extension, is limiting. For instance, I can't control for the speeds, the types of roads that are accessible, or the isocrone generation field types such as overlap.

Is there a way to generate an Isocrone through a form of network analysis either using ORS Tools or another plugin with such control as stated above?

I have done several extensive dives into this topic regarding background research and I just can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Not exactly what you are searching for, but take a look at [openrouteservice](https://maps.openrouteservice.org) and [QNEAT3](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QNEAT3/)

Comment: I looked into this and it wasn't as robust as I had hoped it would be. The Iso-Area of QNEAT3 doesn't, from what I had found, allow for the control of road-speeds or areas within the network in which a vehicle can travel. For instance, I would like to prohibit travel on roads greater than 25 mph while still allowing for the network analysis to account for crossing roads that are greater than 25 mph so long as the crossover is equal to or less than 25 mph. Based on this analysis, I would like to create a more accurate iso-representation rather than a simplified shape.